# Trying to finish this program for my python class, but can't figure out why I'm receiving a TypeError

Tags: python

```
payPerHour = float( input ( "How much do you make per hour?\n"))

regWorkWeek = float( input ( "How many hours is a regular work week for you?\n"))

overtimeRate = float( input ( "What do you make for overtime pay?\n"))

weeksWorked = int( input ( "How many weeks will you be working?\n"))

def regularPay (payPerHour, regWorkWeek, hoursWorked):

     if hoursWorked< regWorkWeek:

         return payPerHour * hoursWorked

     else:
            return payPerHour * regWorkWeek

def overtimePay (payPerHour, regWorkWeek, hoursWorked):

    if hoursWorked > regWorkWeek:
        return ((payPerHour* overtimeRate)*(hoursWorked - regularWorkWeek))





for currentWeek in (1, weeksWorked + 1):
#Receiving error here concerning number of arguments returned, not sure why.
    hoursWorked = int (input("How many hours did you work in week", currentWeek,  "?\n"))

    regularPay()

    overtimePay()

    totalPay = regularPay + overtimePay

    print (float("Week", currentWeek," pay= $", regularPay ,",\n"))
    
    print (float("Overtime pay= $", overtimePay ,",\n"))

    print (float ("total pay= $", totalPay,"."))
```

Comment: Sorry if this is difficult to read, I'm still not 100% sure how to post on here.

Comment: @enzo, I applied the fixes you suggested, but I'm getting a new error from line 45: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ashha/Desktop/cop 2500/payment.py", line 45, in <module>
    totalPay = regularResult + overtimeResult
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'NoneType'
>>>

Comment: In which line you are getting the type error?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of bugs in this code:

- The `regularPay` and `overtimePay` functions weren't being passed their parameters, and the return value wasn't being used.
- The names of those functions collided with the variables that you were trying (I think) to assign the actual return values to.
- `overtimePay` didn't return anything for the non-overtime case (which means you'll get a TypeError when trying to add it).
- You'd typo'd `regWorkWeek` as `regularWorkWeek` in one spot, which would lead to a `NameError`.
- Your print statements had needless `float` conversions around strings that won't convert to floats (this would lead to a `ValueError` if the rest of the program was able to get this far).
- Your `for` loop was iterating over a tuple rather than a `range` as you probably intended.

The whitespace was also kinda all over the place, making it unnecessarily hard to read the code (inconsistent indentation, lots of random linebreaks, etc).

Here's a fixed version:

```
def calcRegularPay(payPerHour, regWorkWeek, hoursWorked):
    if hoursWorked < regWorkWeek:
        return payPerHour * hoursWorked
    else:
        return payPerHour * regWorkWeek


def calcOvertimePay(payPerHour, regWorkWeek, hoursWorked):
    if hoursWorked > regWorkWeek:
        return payPerHour * overtimeRate * (hoursWorked - regWorkWeek)
    else:
        return 0.0


payPerHour = float(input("How much do you make per hour?\n"))
regWorkWeek = float(input("How many hours is a regular work week for you?\n"))
overtimeRate = float(input("What do you make for overtime pay?\n"))
weeksWorked = int(input("How many weeks will you be working?\n"))
for currentWeek in range(1, weeksWorked + 1):
    hoursWorked = int(input(
        f"\nHow many hours did you work in week {currentWeek}?\n"
    ))

    regularPay = calcRegularPay(payPerHour, regWorkWeek, hoursWorked)
    overtimePay = calcOvertimePay(payPerHour, regWorkWeek, hoursWorked)

    print(f"Week {currentWeek} pay= ${regularPay},")
    print(f"Overtime pay= ${overtimePay},")
    print(f"total pay= ${regularPay + overtimePay}.")
```

Working output:

```
How much do you make per hour?
100
How many hours is a regular work week for you?
40
What do you make for overtime pay?
1.5
How many weeks will you be working?
2

How many hours did you work in week 1?
40
Week 1 pay= $4000.0,
Overtime pay= $0.0,
total pay= $4000.0.

How many hours did you work in week 2?
50
Week 2 pay= $4000.0,
Overtime pay= $1500.0,
total pay= $5500.0.
```

Comment: I applied the fixes that you suggested, and I really appreciate your help. Now I'm having an issue where the program won't loop past week two. Here's the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ashha/Desktop/cop 2500/payment.py", line 37, in <module>
    regularPay = regularPay(payPerHour, regWorkWeek, hoursWorked)
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
>>>

Comment: It's hard to figure out whether you wanted something like `regularPay` to be a function, or a variable. In your code, you are redefining `regularPay` to be a variable. That's why when you tried to call the function `regularPay`, it's already been replaced with a floating point value, which you can't call as a function.

Comment: Nevermind, it cleared itself up and I'm not sure what happened. Thank you for your help though, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Note that in my fixed version of this code, the functions have been renamed `calcRegularPay` and `calcOvertimePay` in order to eliminate the naming collision, and there is noplace where I call a function called `regularPay` as seen in your error message.  You were probably running (some part of) the old version of the code.

Comment: I think that's what happened, I undid a couple of changes I made and saw that. Thank you so much!